# Mysql order by amount of rows found

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Mysql 5.5.40.
Say I have a user profile page, and some users my fill as little as two details (username, age) and others may have complete all fields in their profile. So, I would like to query mysql and show all users, but index the users which have filled the most details at the top. I can do this with PHP, but I am trying to find a mysql solution.

#### PHP example.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); 

foreach($result as $row){
  if(count($row) > 10){
      echo $row['username'];
    }elseif(count($row) > 9){
       echo $row['username'];
   }
}
```

You can see how cumbersome this code is, but it does get the job done, and I would like to know if there is a mysql alternative for this.

Comment: it depends on the structure of your MySQL tables. It would be helpful if we can see that. Can you update your question to include that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your details are stored in columns, and the definition of "not filled in" can be different for each column. The [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) statement will cope with many different circumstances:

```
SELECT
   id, 
   CASE WHEN foo IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
   CASE WHEN bar = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
   CASE WHEN numval = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS score
FROM
   users
ORDER BY score
```

`score` will result in a total between 0 and 3. `foo` will count toward the score if it's not null, `bar` will count toward the score if it's not an empty string, `numval` will count toward the score if it's not zero.

Note that there's also an `IF` statement in MySQL, but [it's a non-standard MySQL extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extensions-to-ansi.html), so you should stick with `CASE` if you want your SQL code to be portable to other databases.

Comment: All, `+1` for good answers, but I will have to go with this one. Just trying it now.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have NULL values for columns which are empty, you can use [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) function to get it done.

```
SELECT username, age,
((username IS NULL) + (age IS NULL)) AS empty_count 
FROM users 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY empty_count;
```

`IS NULL` will return `1` if the value of the field is NULL else it will return `0`.

If your values are not null by default, you can use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Something like this: `(IF(username <> '', 0, 1) + IF(age <> 0, 0, 1))`

Though I think it would be better, if you can just keep track of number of fields entered by user and store it in the table in separate column. You have to track the fields on each update though.

Comment: Sadly, there are some fields that store null as `0` or `''` so this won't help. I should've used better data types before for this to happen

Comment: Updated my answer for your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. It's not an elegant solution but it works.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM users
ORDER BY   (LENGTH(column1) > 0) 
         + (LENGTH(column2) > 0)
         + (LENGTH(column3) > 0)
         [...]
   DESC
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, as I am also familiar with the `LENGTH()` function, but a little bit messy, just as my php solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assume str_field1 is a string field and num_field2 is a number field. Then:

```
SELECT
    username,
    age,
    (str_field1 IS NOT NULL AND str_field1 != '') + 
    (num_field2 IS NOT NULL AND num_field2 != 0) + 
    (str_field3 IS NOT NULL AND str_field3 != '') AS weight
FROM users
ORDER BY weight DESC
```